# Editor Wysiwyg no se muestra correctamente

Tags: wordpress, php7, bootstrap-4

estoy usando `ACF`, específicamente el campo del `editor Wysiwyg` para agregar información en una de mis páginas, el problema es que la información resultante no queda exactamente igual al orden que le he colocado en el campo de edición al momento e publicar.

Así es como lo he ordenado en el campo de edición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como queda cuando se ha publicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo de plantilla tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="col-12 pt-2">
  <!-- Espoiler -->
    <p>
       <a class="col-12 btn btn-primary mt-2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1<?php 
         the_field('id'); ?>" role="butto aria-expanded="falsaria-controls="collapse1<?php the_field('id'); ?>">
         Este artículo contiene spoiler Mostrar / Ocultar el contenido
       </a>

       <div class="collapse" id="collapse1<?php the_field('id'); ?>">
       <div class="col-12 d-inline-block justify-content-lg-start">
       <?php the_field('desarrollo_de_la_mision'); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
   </p>
  <!-- Espoiler -->
</div>
```

Donde `<?php the_field('desarrollo_de_la_mision'); ?>` es el campo que pertenece al `editor Wysiwyg`.

He probado con varias clases para el contenedor pero sigue sin funcionar, el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema de css, puede que algún plugin o hoja de estilos este modificando los estilos del editor, sin embargo si es un tema desde cero posiblemente tenga que agregar estilos propios para emular lo del editor, desconozco si es posible importar alguna hoja solo para el editor, si bien WordPress agrega esos estilos al wp_header o directamente a la etiqueta style puede que haya otras hojas de estilos que los modifique.

En todo caso lo recomendable es crear una hoja solo para eso y agregar alguna clase a la parte del contenido para identificar esos estilos.